# ffmpeg avformat_open_input analogue with string input

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

ffmpeg `avformat_open_input()` needs a file name of stream to open.

But my program generates its own SDP file with all information needed into a string.

Is there any analogous function I could use with a string instead of a file? As I don't want to create a file for that.

Or I`ll have to create my own parser for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example from Russian StackOverflow (many thanks for Monah Tuk):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

extern "C" {#include <libavformat/avformat.h>}

using namespace std;

static const char* SDP_DATA = R"(
v=0
o=- 1376063087593 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
m=audio 50008 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtcp:50009 IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=sendrecv
m=video 50010 RTP/AVP 120
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtcp:50011 IN IP4 192.168.2.196
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-fb:* nack
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm fir
)";

struct SdpOpaque
{
    using Vector = std::vector<uint8_t>;
    Vector           data;
    Vector::iterator pos;
};

int sdp_read(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int size)
{
    assert(opaque);
    assert(buf);
    auto octx = static_cast<SdpOpaque*>(opaque);

    if (octx->pos == octx->data.end()) {
        return 0;
    }

    auto dist = static_cast<int>(std::distance(octx->pos, octx->data.end()));
    auto count = std::min(size, dist);

    std::copy(octx->pos, octx->pos + count, buf);
    octx->pos += count;

    return count;
}

int sdp_open(AVFormatContext **pctx, const char *data, AVDictionary **options)
{
    assert(pctx);
    *pctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    assert(*pctx);

    const size_t avioBufferSize = 4096;
    auto avioBuffer = static_cast<uint8_t*>(av_malloc(avioBufferSize));
    auto opaque = new SdpOpaque();

    opaque->data = SdpOpaque::Vector(data, data + strlen(data));
    opaque->pos  = opaque->data.begin();

    auto pbctx = avio_alloc_context(avioBuffer, avioBufferSize, 0, opaque, sdp_read, nullptr, nullptr);
    assert(pbctx);

    (*pctx)->pb = pbctx;

    auto infmt = av_find_input_format("sdp");

    return avformat_open_input(pctx, "memory.sdp", infmt, options);
}

void sdp_close(AVFormatContext **fctx)
{
    assert(fctx);
    auto ctx = *fctx;

    // Opaque can be non-POD type, free it before and assign to null
    auto opaque = static_cast<SdpOpaque*>(ctx->pb->opaque);
    delete opaque;
    ctx->pb->opaque = nullptr;

    avio_close(ctx->pb);
    avformat_close_input(fctx);
}

int main()
{
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    AVFormatContext *sdpctx = nullptr;
    sdp_open(&sdpctx, SDP_DATA, nullptr);

    av_dump_format(sdpctx, 0, "memory.sdp", 0);
    // Copy settings to target context from SDP context:
    /*
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sdpctx->nb_streams; ++i) {
        AVStream *st = avformat_new_stream(otherctx, nullptr);
        st->id = i;
        avcodec_copy_context(st->codec, sdpctx->streams[i]->codec);
        st->time_base = sdpctx->streams[i]->time_base;
    }
    */

    sdp_close(&sdpctx);
    return 0;
}
```

It fully works in VS2013 exept `std::copy`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own input protocol by setting [AVFormatContext->pb](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFormatContext.html#a1e7324262b6b78522e52064daaa7bc87) before calling `avformat_open_input`. The pb should be an [AVIOContext](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_8h.html#a853f5149136a27ffba3207d8520172a5) that has a custom `read` callback that reads from a buffer instead of a file.

Answer (score 1):

I found a more direct way here, [media-receiver-v2/main.cpp](https://github.com/aliakseis/media-receiver-v2/blob/main/main.cpp), thanks to [aliakesis](https://github.com/aliakseis). For example you can just use the code below, the sdpClause is the same in Dmitry's answer.

```
    AVInputFormat *file_iformat = av_find_input_format("sdp");
    AVDictionary *format_opts = NULL;

    std::string url = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8," + sdpClause;

    int error = avformat_open_input(&ic,
        url.c_str(),
        file_iformat,
        &format_opts);
```